# How do I correctly implement Comparable for List in this instance?

Tags: java, list, comparable

What I want to do is use the compareTo() method to compare removedItemFromList1 and removedItemFromList2, then insert whichever value is smaller into the modifiedList3 and put the larger of the two removedFromList 1 or 2 back into its original list.  If I had hair long enough to pull, it would have been pulled out by now...Am I not casting correctly? How do I correctly go about using the compareTo() method to accomplish this?

```
public class List<Integer> implements Comparable 
{
    private ListNode<Integer> firstNode;
    private ListNode<Integer> lastNode;


    public void insertAtBack (Integer insertItem)
    {
        if ( isEmpty())
            firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode<Integer>(insertItem);
        else 
            lastNode = lastNode.nextBasket = new ListNode<Integer>( insertItem );
    }

    public Integer removeFromBack() 
    {   
        Integer removedItem = (Integer) lastNode.topBucketInBasket;

        if ( firstNode == lastNode)
            firstNode = lastNode = null;
        else
        {
            ListNode<Integer> current = firstNode;

            while ( current.nextBasket != lastNode)
                current = current.nextBasket;

            lastNode = current;
            current.nextBasket = null;
        }

        return removedItem;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return firstNode == null;
    }

    public List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2)
    {
        List<Integer> modifiedList3 = new List<Integer>();

         Integer removedItemFromList1 = (Integer) list1.removeFromBack();
         Integer removedItemFromList2 = (Integer) list2.removeFromBack();

          ((Comparable) removedItemFromList1).compareTo( removedItemFromList2);

         int comparison = compareTo(removedItemFromList2);

         if ( comparison == 1)
            modifiedList3.insertAtBack(removedItemFromList2); 
            list1.insertAtBack(removedItemFromList1);

         if ( comparison == -1)
             modifiedList3.insertAtBack(removedItemFromList1);
            list2.insertAtBack(removedItemFromList2);

        return modifiedList3;   
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Integer itemToCompare)
    {
        final int BEFORE = -1;
        final int AFTER = 1;
        if (this.removedItemFromList1 < list2.removedItemFromList2) return BEFORE;
        if (this.removedItemFromList1 > list2.removedItemFromList2) return AFTER;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement the generic version `Comparable<Integer>` instead of the raw version `Comparable`.

Also, in the following

```
public class List<Integer> implements Comparable
```

That `Integer` is not the same as `java.lang.Integer`. Actually, it's something called formal type parameter in that context.

You probably want to change it to

```
//List is kind of ambiguous with java.util.List
public class MyList<E> implements Comparable<Integer> {
```

or may be something else instead of `MyList`.

If you implement `Comparable` it should be

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object itemToCompare) {
```

and if `Comparable<Integer>` (which is the one you are after, I guess), it should be

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Integer itemToCompare)
```

The difference is the parameter types - `Object` and `Integer`.

It's kind of messy and not so clear what you are trying to acheive.

But the point that your `List` class implements `Comparable` indicates that you want to compare an instance of `List` with another instance. If that's the case then it should like something like this -

```
public class MyList<E> implements Comparable<MyList> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyList other) {
        //compare and return result
    }
```

But the fact that the parameter type is `Integer` suggest that what you are actually trying to compare are `Integer`s, in which case `Integer` is already `Comparable`.

```
((Comparable) removedItemFromList1).compareTo( removedItemFromList2);
```

You don't need to do all that

```
removedItemFromList1.compareTo(removedItemFromList2);
```

is enough. And if that's all you need then you don't need implement `Comparable` at all, so can remove that `compareTo` method also.

Comment: ---thanks for pointing that out. Can you see clearly what it is that I'm doing wrong within the copmareTo() method?  Why is compiler unhappy?  How do I correctly compare the two above named fields?

Comment: Can you school me on the meaning of the difference regarding Integer and java.lang.Integer?

Comment: I understand your revisions, but what I don't quite comprehend is how to accomplish the method compareTo() successfully.  Inside the compareTo method, Eclipse gives me indicator that list1(which I just changed from this.  to list1 for both instances) and list2 objects can't be defined as variables. What this mean?  How do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

The Comparable interface goes this way

```
public interface Comparable<T> {

  public int compareTo(T t){




  }

}
```

You should use the `Type Parameter`. **Comparable** is Type Parametrized.

So try it this way...

```
public class mList<Integer> implements Comparable<Integer>{


......



     public int compareTo(Integer itemToCompare){


        .....

    }



}
```