# Java order a collection

Tags: java, comparable

I have this map:

```
Map<Integer,List<EventiPerGiorno>> mapEventi=new HashMap<Integer,List<EventiPerGiorno>>();
```

where **EventiPerGiorno** is a **Comparable** object.
How can I get a sorted list from the map?

I tried with

```
Collection<List<EventiPerGiorno>> collection=mapEventi.values()
Comparable.sort(collection);
```

But Comparable.sort() doesn't like the list as comparable. Is there a ComparableList?

*EDIT*

this is the comparable method...

```
public class EventiPerGiorno implements Comparable<EventiPerGiorno>{


    @Override
    public int compareTo(EventiPerGiorno o) {
        return this.getPrimoSpettacolo().compareTo(o.getPrimoSpettacolo());
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show how you implemented Comparable for EventiPerGiorno?

Comment: The problem is that you have a List of Lists.  What exactly do you want to sort the list of lists on?  Size?

Comment: As "EventiPerGiorno" is Italian for "events per day" I presume that you somehow want to order the events on that. However, it is unclear to me whether you want to keep them in a collection of lists. Or is it OK to put all of them in one single list and sort _that_?

Comment: I wrote: "EventiPerGiorno is a Comparable object" so this implements the compareTo method and this is what I want to use to sort the list. Thanks

Comment: Even after you accepted an answer, the question is still unintelligible. I've no idea what objects you're trying to sort (EventiPerGiornos, Lists, Maps, Collections ?) or on what criteria they're to be compared.

Comment: @Boann you're right, I want to order the List object. The List object itself must be ordered by EventiPerGiorno comparable method.

Comment: An individual list from the map or a list containing all the objects from all the lists in the map put together?

Comment: I'd still like to know what the real question was.

Comment: I had to create a YourComparableList class with comparable method that itself uses the EventiPerGiorno.compareTo() for each items.

Comment: @Tobia You didn't have to. If your list items are comparable, you can just call `Collections.sort`, and it doesn't matter what type of list you use. The "YourComparableList" answer was for sorting **a list of lists** and will not sort the EventiPerGiorno objects at all. If you want to sort EventiPerGiorno objects, all you need is a single `Collections.sort` call. See my answer below.

Comment: I need to get all List<EventiPerGiorno> in the map ordered by EventiPerGiorno. So I had to put all lists in another (bigger) list and then sort it.

Comment: I still don't know whether you wanted a `List<EventiPerGiorno>` sorted using the comparator shown above, or a `List<List<EventiPerGiorno>>` sorted based on some mysterious and unexplained criteria, but I give up trying to understand it. Sorry to bother you. :-/

Comment: You really don't involve the sorting criteria, you just have to think about "Comparable" interface... what is written into compareTo method really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Tobia "what is written into compareTo method really doesn't matter". It does absolutely matter. Of course it matters. It's the most important part. You're spouting total nonsense now. You can't just `return 0;` and expect it to compare objects correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `Collections` don't have any order associated with them.  You could turn the `Collection` into a `List` first and then sort it.

```
Collection<List<EventiPerGiorno>> collection = mapEventi.values()
YourComparableList<List<EventiPerGiorno>> list = new YourComparableList(collection);
Collections.sort(list);
```

For this, you will need to create some sort of `List` that implements `Comparable`.  See [How do I correctly implement Comparable for List in this instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775772/how-do-i-correctly-implement-comparable-for-list-in-this-instance) for an example.

Note that this is sorting the objects of type `List<EventiPerGiorno>`, not the objects of type `EventiPerGiorno`.  If you are interested in sorting the latter, you might want this instead:

```
ArrayList<EventiPerGiorno> bigList = new ArrayList<EventiPerGiorno>();
for (List<EventiPerGiorno> list : mapEventi.values()) {
    bigList.addAll(list);
}
Collections.sort(bigList);
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to wrap List<EventiPerGiorno> in Collection, is it? Same goes for the ArrayList

Comment: @AndrewJones your code above is trying to sort a Collection of Lists.  Is that what you really want to do? Or are you trying to sort each List itself.

Comment: @AndrewJones and Dodd10x I agree that it is strange to sort lists rather than the contents of the list, but that seems to be what the questioner wants to do.

Comment: Got it. I missed that he was trying to sort the Collection of Lists and thought he was just trying to sort the contents of the Lists.

Comment: @AndrewJones I just added a second paragraph to my answer to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: Your first block of code will not work.  Per the API on Collections.sort:  *All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface.*  Neither `List` nor `ArrayList` do.

Comment: @MadConan Good point! I've edited my response to reflect that.

Comment: I had to wrote a "YourComparableList" extending ArrayList to order by List object.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to sort a List of Lists.  List doesn't implement Comparable.  You'll have to create your own Comparator instance.

```
    Map<String, List<EventiPerGiorno>> map = new HashMap<String, List<EventiPerGiorno>>();

    List<List<EventiPerGiorno>> lists = new ArrayList(map.values());

    Collections.sort(lists, new Comparator<List<EventiPerGiorno>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<EventiPerGiorno> o1, List<EventiPerGiorno> o2) {
            // ??? This is up to you.
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will sort every list in your map:

```
for (List<EventiPerGiorno> list : mapEventi.values()) {
    Collections.sort(list);
}
```

Or if you perhaps want to retrieve a single sorted list without modifying the lists in the map:

```
int someKey = ...;
List<EventiPerGiorno> list = new ArrayList<>(mapEventi.get(someKey));
Collections.sort(list);
return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to extend List and make it implement Comparable.  There is no default natural ordering that can be used to compare multiple Lists.

The collections framework wouldnt know if you wanted to sort the list by number of items, number of duplicates, or values within the list.

Then to sort you use:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29